# Google Sheets : how to show a specific result from a query that sums timestamps for each day?

Tags: google-sheets, timestamp, formula, counting

I'm trying to auto-sum the number of submissions from a form and display only the results for the current day.

I used this formula

> =Query('Form Responses'!A1:A,"select COUNT(A) where A is not null group by YEAR(A), MONTH(A)+1,DAY(A) order by 'A' desc label Count(A) '# Screenings Today'", true)

to display the dates and quantity of submissions for each of those dates.

How can I only show the quantity of submissions for today?  And tomorrow, to show the quantity of submissions for tomorrow and so on?

For example, the formula above returned

'# Screenings Today

10
28
16
21
27
3

How can I get it to only show "3" and then tomorrow it would count and display the submissions for that day?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a query if the quantity is the only information you are trying to pull. You can use the COUNTIF(range, criterion) function.

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A, TODAY())
```

The TODAY() function returns the current date as a date value.

Comment: Hi BigRed, I tried your formula but the outcome was zero.  Is that because the field it's counting is a timestamp consisting of date & time and today() is only date?